# How to use boost::asio::buffer in a method parameter

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use [boost::asio::buffer](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/boost/group__buffer.html) as a reference parameter in my method like this:

```
void ReadDataIntoBufferPassedIn(boost::asio::buffer & buffer);
```

Firstly, compiler complains that:

```
error: no type named 'buffer' in namespace 'boost::asio' void ReadDataIntoBufferPassedIn(boost::asio::buffer & buffer);
```

This looks like it requires me to templatise the method here, but my question is a little beyond just fixing the error.

**Question:**
What is the best way to do this without causing extra copies of the `asio::buffer` I pass in? a *templatised* way? How? If not, how can I resolve this error & still be able to pass in `boost::asio::buffer` as a method param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it is not clear to me if you are aware that the `boost::asio::buffer` is a **function** that creates buffer objects (mutable or const), so this explains the compilation error. Buffer object is just a handle to some contiguous chunk of memory and it contains just a pointer to the raw data and the size of it - a (`void*`, `size_t`) pair.

If you need to modify the underlying data you can do this by passing a reference to mutable_buffer and fiddling with it as shown in:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer.html but it should be much safer (type-safety-wise) to just pass the actual container for your data instead of the `buffer` view of it.

UPDATE:
You don't really need to make your function a template as you suggest in the other answer. Also, an rvalue reference may not be needed. It all depends on what you want to do with the function.

```cpp
void ReadDataIntoBufferPassedIn(const boost::asio::mutable_buffer& buffer) {
   int* p = boost::asio::buffer_cast<int*>(buffer);
   *p = 5; // Do whatever you want with p
}

std::vector<int> v{1,2,3}; 
ReadDataIntoBufferPassedIn(boost::asio::buffer(v));
```

Comment: yes. you are correct. I misunderstood that `boost::asio::buffer` is a function. this is why it needs to be a `&&` to pass it in may be. I have put the below answer stating how exactly this needs to be done. My whole objective was to be able to use `boost::asio::buffer` as a param to enable reuse of this method properly

Comment: The documentation helps out: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html

Comment: accepting this answer as it points out the root cause of why the code in my question did not work

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I need to **templatise with universal reference** like this be able to pass in a prepared `boost::asio::buffer` into my method.

```
template <class TheBuffer>
void ReadDataIntoBufferPassedIn(TheBuffer && buffer) {

}
```

Above technique works well **invoking** the method in this way **for example**:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buf;
ReadDataIntoBufferPassedIn(boost::asio::buffer(buf));
```

There are other ways also the invocation fits in well.

Comment: You can simply pass by ref. `buffer` is a bit like string_view in that sense: it's a lightweight reference only